# Node.js Modifying variable from different file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new in Node.js and I wondering something. I'm use express and socket.io. there is some value to should be changeable, let's say this 'flag' that have boolean type variable - this is `'false'` at default.

but some moment especially when I click some button, it would be change to `'true'`. the express and socket.io workflow is fine, but I don't know how to modifying variable from different file not just copying it.

Please see below code to understand

**Main.js**

```
var flag = false;
exports.flag = flag; 

// display flag every second
setInterval((function(){console.log(flag)}), 1000);
```

**Remote.js**

```
// I want to change 'original flag' at main.js in remote.js 
// How can I do that? I think below is just copying it, so doesn't effect to main.js

flag = require('/Main').flag;

// the flag will be 'true' after some moment
flag = true;
```

**expected result I want in main.js**

```
false
false
false
...
true
true
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the included object instead of the property ?

That way you keep a reference on the object and not the primitive value.

```
main = require('/Main');

main.flag = true;
```

Edit : 
As said in the comment by Mike C, you would also need to use the object in the setInterval

```
setInterval((function(){console.log(exports.flag)}), 1000);
```

It works because `Object` is a reference type, compared to `string` or `boolean` which are primitive.

Comment: They'd also have to change the code in `main.js` to use `exports.flag` in the `setInterval`.

Comment: Added more details :)

Answer (score 1):

you can define a global variable and access is or change it wherever you want.

**main.js**

```
global.flag = false; 

// display flag every second
setInterval((function(){console.log(global.flag)}), 1000);
```

**remote.js**

```
// the flag will be 'true' after some moment
global.flag = true;
```

Comment: Thank you too, maybe this is easy way.